# How do I stop Angular from removing HTML comments?

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 9 app with comments such as `<!--googleoff: all-->`. These comments tell Google what part of the page not to index. I've noticed that Angular removes these comments so Google ends up indexing the entire page which is not what I want.

How do I prevent Angular from removing these comments?

Comment: If this is for SEO, try [server side rendering](https://angular.io/guide/universal)

Comment: I'm already using prerender.io to do server side rendering caching

Comment: Hi, were you able to find a solution? I also need angular to stop removing <!-- html comments --> in components